# How to add dynamically a column to a table layout based on the number of rows in the table?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table that potentially has enough rows to fill up the screen, and I'd like to be able to add another column instead of taking up vertical space on the page. At a certain point (8 rows?) I'd like the rest of the rows to shift over into a new column.

What I have now:

[image]

What I want:
[image]

Here is an example of the html of the table:

```
<table class="base-table">
    <thead>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>min</td>
        <td>avg</td>
        <td>max</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
            <td><div style="border:1px solid #ccc;padding:1px;background: white;"><div style="width:4px;height:0;border:5px solid rgb(255, 0, 0);overflow:hidden"></div></div></td>
            <td class="disabled"> stuff </td>
            <td class="disabled"> stuff </td>
            <td class="disabled"> stuff </td>
            <td class="disabled"> stuff </td>
            <td><button id="refresh-stats">Refresh</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you add a shortened version of your table HTML? We don't need all of the rows, but perhaps some will find 2-3 example rows useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis for what you need to do is keep a count of the current cell number that you want to append and reset it after every 8th addition.   This should at least get you started; some of the appending will probably be more complex for you:

```
var row = 1, table = document.querySelector('table');
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!table.rows[row % 8]) {
        table.appendChild(document.createElement('tr'));
    }
    table.rows[row++ % 8].appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/kVmgm/

Answer (score 0):

When you reach the max number of rows you want, just create a new table. If you float them left, you'll get the desired effect